# Spring Cloud Data Flow : Value too long for column "TASK_NAME" (DeployerPartitionHandler with Spring Batch)

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a simple Spring Batch Job running Kubernetes as a Spring Cloud Task. This job uses Spring Batch Partitioning to further launch partitioned steps as task pods on the same Kubernetes cluster.

**Main job : (Relevant parts)**

```
@Bean
public Job mainControllerJob() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating mainControllerJobbean...");
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainControllerJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(testStep(null, null, null)).build();
}

@Bean
public Step testStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        @Qualifier("testPartitioner") Partitioner partitioner, PartitionHandler partitionHandler) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating testStep");
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")
            .partitioner("testWorkerStep", partitioner).partitionHandler(partitionHandler).build();
}

@Bean
public DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler(@Value("${test.partion.app}") String resourceLocation,
        @Value("${test.application.name}") String applicationName, ApplicationContext context,
        TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer, DockerResourceLoader dockerResourceLoader) {
    Resource resource = dockerResourceLoader.getResource(resourceLocation);
    DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource,
            "testWorkerStep", taskRepository);

    List<String> commandLineArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");

    commandLineArgs.addAll(Arrays.stream(applicationArguments.getSourceArgs()).filter(
            x -> !x.startsWith("--spring.profiles.active=") && !x.startsWith("--spring.cloud.task.executionid="))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    commandLineArgs.addAll(applicationArguments.getNonOptionArgs());

    partitionHandler.setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs));
    partitionHandler.setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(new NoOpEnvironmentVariablesProvider());
    partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(maxWorkers);
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(gridSize);
    partitionHandler.setApplicationName(applicationName);

    return partitionHandler;
}
```

When the child step (task pod) is launched on k8 by the above job, I see the following exception for the child step :

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE TASK_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, TASK_NAME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ?, PARENT_EXECUTION_ID = ? where TASK_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; 
Value too long for column """TASK_NAME"" VARCHAR(100)": "'test-app,test-app_testJob_testWorkerStep:partition5800' (106)"; 
SQL statement:
    UPDATE TASK_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, TASK_NAME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ?, PARENT_EXECUTION_ID = ? where TASK_EXECUTION_ID = ? [22001-199]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Value too long for column """TASK_NAME"" VARCHAR(100)"
```

The error is clear. I need to somehow shorten the name of the child partion step so that it fits within th ecolumn width of the the internal TASK_EXECUTION table.

**What I want to understand is how can I change the name of the child partition step launched by a Spring Batch Job myself?**

I roughly understand that the step name is being created by [SimpleStepExecutionSplitter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.java#L183-L184). However, I don't see a way to override this behavior programatically. How can I change the child step name and also ensure that I do that in a way that it does not impact the restartability of my jobs/steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker step name is the concatenation of the step name and the partition name (with a separator in between). Partition names can be customized using a [PartitionNameProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/PartitionNameProvider.html). So if you want to have control on how partition names  are generated, you need to make your `Partitioner` implement the `PartitionNameProvider` interface.

Another option is to increase the size of the `TASK_NAME` column.

Comment: I did not understand how to use the `PartitionNameProvider` interface (`getPartitionNames(int gridSize)` ) -> Does this mean I have to return a list of names for all my partitions where each index position represents the name for that partition number? Also, I thought of changing the size of the `TASK_NAME` column but could not find a way to ask data flow server to use my custom DDL. I posted a question on similar lines : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023823/spring-cloud-data-flow-custom-ddl-for-data-flow-server

Comment: Yes, you should return the names of your partitions. The grid size is the same value as in `Partitioner#partition(int gridSize)` which is basically the number of partitions (but is only a hint as there are use cases where it is not used, such as in `MultiResourcePartitioner`).