# Spring Cloud Data Flow : Custom DDL for Data Flow Server

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have setup a  Spring Cloud Data Flow server on Kubernetes backed by an in-memory h2 database running on Kubernetes as well.

I want to change the length of the columns in some of the tables that are created by SCDF. For example, I want to change the length of the `TASK_PARAM`  column in the `TASK_EXECUTION_PARAMS` table from 2500 to 10000 characters.

I want to do this because the input arguments that I am passing to a Task are comma separated list of 100 account numbers. This does not fit in the default length of 2500 characteters.

**Question :**  Is there a way to supply a custom SQL DDL to Spring Cloud Data Flow Server so that it uses this DDL to create the metadata tables instead of using the default DDL?

Note : I can always pre-create these tables so SCDF uses them as-is; however, what I want is for SCDF to create these tables using the DDL I provided when it starts up instead of using the default DDL.